# DTMF detection using Goertzel Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, signal-processing, dtmf, goertzel-algorithm

How can I use Goertzel Algorithm if the wave format are the following:
 - 2 Channels
 - 32 bit
 - 48 kHz

I already searched about Goertzel algorithm but all I can see all over the internet is detection of DTMF with wave format of 2 Channels, 16 bit, and 8 kHz. I don't know what part of code should I modify to meet my requirements.

```
Private Function Goertzel(ByVal sample As Byte(), ByVal N As Long, _
                          ByVal freq As Double, ByVal sampr As Long) As Double
    Dim Skn As Double = 0
    Dim Skn1 As Double = 0
    Dim Skn2 As Double
    Dim c As Double
    Dim c2 As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    c = 2 * Math.PI * freq / sampr
    c2 = Math.Cos(c)

    For i = 0 To (N - 1)
        Skn2 = Skn1
        Skn1 = Skn
        Skn = 2 * c2 * Skn1 - Skn2 + sample(i)
    Next

    Return Skn - Math.Exp(-c) * Skn1
End Function

Private Function power(ByVal val As Double) As Double
    Return 20 * Math.Log(Math.Abs(val)) / Math.Log(10)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you simply convert the wav?

Comment: I tried to convert the wave format of the given wav. Unfortunately when I played it, it sounds horrible and no DTMF was detected. By the way, I'm using TAPIEx.Net lib for test purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good description of the Goertzel algorithm (there are [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) on the web) should include parameterization for sample rate, filter frequency, and duration.  Just leave the filter frequency and duration the same and change the sample rate parameter of the filter.

Comment: I know the sample rate that I'll be using as mentioned above. I think I'll use 100ms for duration but if you know some formula to get the appropriate duration for mentioned wave format above please let me know. I have no idea about filter frequency, If you can give me an example I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Any existing code you find should include all the DTMF tone frequencies.

Comment: @hotpw2. Hi there. I posted the code that I use above. I know where to get the values for each parameter except for `freq` (frequency). Any idea where can I get that? Or is there a formula in getting frequency given the sample bytes()?

Comment: Wikipedia has a Page on DTMF including the tone frequencies (used in pairs, as in D.)