# Frequency detection in a buffer from microphone windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, fft, frequency, microphone

I develop in c# for wp8.1(I'm a starter)

I send from one phone a series of binary string that is represented like this (for example): "01010101011111000101100". Each '1' is a sinus frequency of 15000 Hz and duration of 10ms. '0' is a silence.

On my other phone I want to detect the string. I thought of using FFT algorithm to detect the strength of the freuquency but I'm not sure.

Do you have some original idea for me how to implement the detection? 
Thanks@!!

Comment: FFT is inappropriate for this. Search StackOverflow for "Goertzel", e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189644/dtmf-detection-using-goertzel-algorithm) - this is a simple algorithm that is widely used in tone detection. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm

Comment: The worse problem than detection will be echoes.  At 10 mS, a wall or hard surface 5 feet away will turn a 0 into a 1.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments. If I use these Goertzel, can I listen to the Microphone in "Real Time" in c# and just wait for a detection of one of my freqs? Thanks